# Is the Wesleyan Quadrilateral present in Luther or in any other pre-Wesley theologians, Protestant or Catholic?

Tags: catholicism, protestantism, martin-luther, lutheranism, wesleyanism

[The Wesleyan Quadrilateral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wesleyan_Quadrilateral), also known as the Methodist Quadrilateral, is a method of theological reflection and of arriving at theological conclusions based on *scripture, tradition, reason,* and *experience.*

According to the Wikipedia article linked above, it is attributed to [John Wesley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wesley), founder of Methodism, though the term "the Wesleyan Quadrilateral" was coined by 20th century American Methodist scholar [Albert C. Outler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Outler).

My question:

Is the substance of the Wesleyan Quadrilateral (drawing theological conclusions based on scripture, tradition, reason, and experience) present in Martin Luther's writings, or in any other pre-Wesley theologians in the Western Christian tradition, Protestant or Catholic?

I am especially looking for clear or fairly clear formulations of this four-point system, though I would also be interested in more implicit appearances of this method in pre-Wesley Protestant or Catholic theologians.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anyone who made this formulation explicit. One example of where all four are present is in the Confessions of Augustine:

1. Scripture: *Confessions* quotes from scripture extensively.
2. Reason: Augustine describes at length the importance of Cicero and Plato in his conversion, and how even there he saw God's light through their reason.
3. Experience: the *Confessions* takes several examples from Augustine's own experience was important in his conversion and later theological work and conclusions. He meditates (for a few examples) on stealing a pear just because he felt like it, his experience as a Manichaean, his conversion experience, and dealing with death of loved ones.
4. Tradition: One sees the importance of Ambrose and Augustine's mother Monica in both his conversion and his ongoing contemplation of the Faith.

Answer (score 0):

Richard Hooker, a 16th Century Anglican Priest and one of the major architects of the early Church of England, said theology was derived from a combination of scripture, tradition, and reason. This has since become known as the "three-legged stool of Anglicanism." John Wesley was an Anglican Priest (and Methodism began as a movement within the Anglican Church), so it is highly likely he was familiar with this formula and expanded it to four points by adding experience.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you provide any references as to where Hooker said this? I would like to be able to read the source(s), and see it in its context. Thank you.

Comment: @LeeWoofenden It's from *Of the Lawes of Ecclesiastical Polity* (see [here](https://www.episcopalchurch.org/glossary/hooker-richard/)).  But while Anglicans agree that there are three sources, they are not equal, so one Anglican scholar prefers ["three levels of a tower"](https://virtueonline.org/three-legged-stool-anglicanism-robert-s-munday).  Page 14-15 [The Use and Abuse of John Calvin in Richard Hooker's Defence of the English Church](https://tspace.library.utoronto.ca/bitstream/1807/101842/1/The%20Use%20and%20Abuse%20of%20John%20Calvin%20in%20Richard%20Hooker.pdf) also discusses this.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple The source reference on Hooker's statement would be a good addition to the answer. Thanks for the rest, also. Perhaps you'd be interested in writing your own answer?